# Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'T'

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following class:

```
class MyClass {

    public each<T extends MyClass>(callback: (item: T) => void): T {
        /* Loop through an array and apply the callback */
        return this;
    }

}


class MyClass2 extends MyClass {

    public before(html: string): MyClass2 {
        return this.each<MyClass2>(item => { /* Do Some Stuff */ });
    }

}
```

I am then getting this error:

> [ts] Type 'this' is not assignable to type 'T'.

How can I return the class instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [this type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#polymorphic-this-types) to represent that `each` returns the instance of the same type for which it was called:

```
class MyClass {

    public each<T extends MyClass>(callback: (item: T) => void): this {
        /* Loop through an array and apply the callback */
        return this;
    }

}

class Derived extends MyClass {
    foo: string;
}

let derived = new Derived;

derived = derived.each(() => {});
```

Note that this type is not the same as `T` - T is a type for array items, it may or may not be the same as the instance type for which you are calling `each` method.

Answer (score 3):

To return the instance of `MyClass` you need to change the return type to `MyClass`

```
public each<T extends MyClass>(callback: (item: T) => void): MyClass {
    /* Loop through an array and apply the callback */
    return this;
}
```

Comment: I then get a new error that says `Type 'MyClass' is not assignable to type 'MyClassExtended'`. where `MyClassExtended extends MyClass`.

Comment: Can you show the code where you assign the result of the function please?

Answer (score 1):

In your `each` method, you should return the base class since `this` refers to a type of `MyClass`. In your `before` method, you could then cast the `MyClass` object back to a `MyClass2` object.

```
class MyClass {
  public each<T extends MyClass>(callback: (item: T) => void): MyClass {
    /* Loop through an array and apply the callback */
    return this;
  }
}

class MyClass2 extends MyClass {
  public before(html: string): MyClass2 {
    return <MyClass2>this.each(item => { /* Do Some Stuff */ });
  }
}
```

checked to see if it transpiles and returns an instance of `MyClass2`:

```
let myclass2 = new MyClass2();
console.log(myclass2.before('') instanceof MyClass2); // returns true
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do is called downcasting: your function returns a T which is a subclass of MyClass but your actual return type is MyClass, a superclass of T.

Polymorphisme by inheritance usually allows you to go up, not down, because subtypes are normally wider (more fields) and you'd end up using an object that doesn't have all the properties you'd expect.

I'm not very familiar with typescript but I found that you can let it fly by transtyping like this 
`return <MyClass>this;`
it should work but it's generally considered bad practice for the reason stated above.

See http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/gilf/2013/01/18/using-casting-in-typescript/ for details on transtyping in typescript.